# How to fix the error I am getting when trying to integrate firebase auth phone number sign-in in a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to integrate firebase auth in a simple page to comply with play store requirements to be able to delete your account through the web.

My accounts are tied to phone numbers so I just need the user to login with their phone number and delete their account.

I have been trying to do it, but I keep getting a Firebase Internal Error, based on the stacktrace the recaptcha fails, but I can't figure out what to do. The documentation only contains snippets, but not a full example so I'm not really sure. I would appreciate if somebody can point me to a solution.

Here is my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Delete your account</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Firebase Auth Demo</h1>

    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
            margin: 20px;
        }

        h1 {
            color: #333;
        }

        button {
            padding: 10px;
            margin: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
        }

        form {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            max-width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        input {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }
    </style>

    <div id="login-container">
        <form id="phone-form">
            <label for="phone">Enter your phone number:</label>
            <input type="tel" id="phone" required>
            <button type="submit" id="sign-in-button">Login with
                Phone Number</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="delete-account-container" style="display:none;">
        <button onclick="deleteAccount()">Delete Account and Data</button>
    </div>

    <script type="module">

        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-app.js";
        import { getAuth, signInWithPhoneNumber, RecaptchaVerifier } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.1/firebase-auth.js"

        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "*********",
            authDomain: "*********",
            projectId: "*********",
            storageBucket: "*********",
            messagingSenderId: "*********",
            appId: "*********"
        };

        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        const auth = getAuth(app);

        document.getElementById("phone-form").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            loginWithPhone();
        });

        window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, "sign-in-button", {
            'size': 'invisible',
            'callback': (response) => {
                console.log('I got called!');
                alert('I got called!');
                // reCAPTCHA solved, allow signInWithPhoneNumber.
                // loginWithPhone();
            }
        });

        const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;

        console.log('RecaptchaVerifier created:', appVerifier);

        window.loginWithPhone = function () {
            const phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone").value;

            console.log(phoneNumber)


            signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
                .then((confirmationResult) => {
                    let code = prompt("Enter the verification code sent to your phone:");
                    return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
                })
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log("Successfully logged in:", result.user);
                    showDeleteButton();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.error("Login failed:", error);
                });
        }

        window.showDeleteButton = function () {
            document.getElementById("login-container").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("delete-account-container").style.display = "block";
        }

        window.deleteAccount = function () {
            if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete your account and data?")) {
                auth.currentUser.delete()
                    .then(() => {
                        console.log("Account deleted successfully.");
                        alert("Account deleted successfully.");
                        window.location.reload();
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.error("Account deletion failed:", error);
                        alert("Account deletion failed. Please try again.");
                    });
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The error and stacktrace I get is the following:

```
Login failed: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).
    FirebaseError errors.ts:76
    create errors.ts:134
    createErrorInternal assert.ts:161
    _assert assert.ts:261
    init recaptcha_verifier.ts:258
    makeRenderPromise recaptcha_verifier.ts:240
    render recaptcha_verifier.ts:173
    verify recaptcha_verifier.ts:132
    _verifyPhoneNumber phone.ts:190
    signInWithPhoneNumber phone.ts:111
    loginWithPhone index.html:112
    <anonymous> index.html:89
    EventListener.handleEvent* index.html:83
```

Thank you.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited the question to include the error and stacktrace.